# Pad Zero before first hypen and remove spaces and add BA and IN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data as below

```
98-45.3A-22
104-44.0A-23
00983-29.1-22
01757-42.5A-22
04968-37.3A2-23
```

Output Looking for output as below in SQL Server

```
00098-BA45.3A-IN-22
00104-BA44.0A-IN-23
00983-BA29.1-IN-22
01757-BA42.5A-IN-22
04968-BA37.3A2-IN-23
```

Comment: Are we guaranteed that the final segment will always be a hyphen followed by exactly 2 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = '98-45.3A-22'
SELECT  ISNULL(REPLICATE('0',6 - CHARINDEX('-',@String)),'')        -- Add leading Zeros
        + STUFF(
                STUFF(@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String),1,'-BA'),      -- Add 'BA'
                CHARINDEX('-',@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1)+2,  -- 2 additional for the character 'BA' 
                1,'-IN')    --  Add 'IN'
```

What if I have more than 6 digit number before first hyphen and want to remove the leading zeros to make it 6 digits.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100) = '0000098-45.3A-22'
SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',@String) <= 6 
            THEN ISNULL(REPLICATE('0',6 - CHARINDEX('-',@String)),'')        -- Add leading Zeros
                + STUFF(
                        STUFF(  @String,CHARINDEX('-',@String),1,'-BA'),      -- Add 'BA'
                        CHARINDEX('-',@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1)+2,  -- 2 additional for the character 'BA' 
                        1,'-IN')    --  Add 'IN'
            ELSE STUFF(
                        STUFF(
                                STUFF(@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String),1,'-BA'),      -- Add 'BA'
                                CHARINDEX('-',@String,CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1)+2,  -- 2 additional for the character 'BA' 
                                1,'-IN'),    --  Add 'IN'
                        1, CHARINDEX('-',@String) - 6, ''       -- remove extra leading Zeros
                        )
        END
```

Comment: What about `BA` and `IN` ?

Comment: @Jatin Patel, this works but I am looking for BA and IN to add to the column

Comment: Right, @sagi I missed `BA` and `IN`, included now.

Comment: @ Jatin Patel: What if I have more than 6 digit number before first hypen and remove the leaading zeros to make it 6 digits again along with the above code that you have given?

Comment: @Vinay, Please check I have added another solution.

Answer (score 3):

I splitted  parts to cope with tricky data templates. This should work even with non-dash-2-digit tail:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('98-45.3A-22'),
    ('104-44.0A-23'),
    ('00983-29.1-22'),
    ('01757-42.5A-22'),
    ('04968-37.3A2-23')
    ) T(X)
), Parts AS
(
    SELECT *,
    RIGHT('00000'+SUBSTRING(X, 1, CHARINDEX('-',X, 1)-1),5) Front,
    'BA'+SUBSTRING(X, CHARINDEX('-',X, 1)+1, 2) BA,
    SUBSTRING(X, PATINDEX('%.%',X), LEN(X)-CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(X), 1)-PATINDEX('%.%',X)+1)  P,
    SUBSTRING(X, LEN(X)-CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(X), 1)+1, LEN(X)) En
    FROM Src
)
SELECT Front+'-'+BA+P+'-IN'+En
FROM Parts
```

It returns:

```
00098-BA45.3A-IN-22
00104-BA44.0A-IN-23
00983-BA29.1-IN-22
01757-BA42.5A-IN-22
04968-BA37.3A2-IN-23
```

Answer (score 1):

Making assumptions that the format is consistent (e.g. always ends with "-" + 2 characters....)

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Col1 VARCHAR(100))
INSERT @Data ( Col1 )
SELECT Col1 
FROM (
    VALUES ('98-45.3A-22'), ('104-44.0A-23'),
        ('00983-29.1-22'), ('01757-42.5A-22'),
        ('04968-37.3A2-23')
) x (Col1)


SELECT RIGHT('0000' + LEFT(Col1, CHARINDEX('-', Col1) - 1), 5)
    + '-BA' + SUBSTRING(Col1, CHARINDEX('-', Col1) + 1, CHARINDEX('.', Col1) - CHARINDEX('-', Col1))
    + SUBSTRING(Col1, CHARINDEX('.', Col1) + 1, LEN(Col1) - CHARINDEX('.', Col1) -  3)
    + '-IN-' + RIGHT(Col1, 2)
FROM @Data
```

It's not ideal IMO to do this string manipulation all the time in SQL. You could shift it out to your presentation layer, or store the pre-formatted value in the db to save the cost of this every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use **REPLICATE** AND **CHARINDEX**:

**Replicate:** will repeat given character till reach required count specify in function

**CharIndex:** Finds the first occurrence of any character

```
Declare @Data AS VARCHAR(50)='98-45.3A-22'
SELECT REPLICATE('0',6-CHARINDEX('-',@Data)) + @Data    

SELECT 
    SUBSTRING
    (
        (REPLICATE('0',6-CHARINDEX('-',@Data)) +@Data)
        ,0
        ,6
    )
    +'-'+'BA'+  CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@Data,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
    +'-'+ 'IN'+ '-' + CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@Data,'-','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 0):

In another way by using `PARSENAME()` you can use this query:

```
 WITH t AS (
SELECT 
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(s, '.', '@@@'), '-', '.'), 3) AS p1,
    REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(s, '.', '@@@'), '-', '.'), 2), '@@@', '.') AS p2,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(s, '.', '@@@'), '-', '.'), 1) AS p3
FROM yourTable)
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + p1, 5) + '-BA' + p2 + '-IN-' + p3
FROM t;
```